# iOS Core-Data Model from Relational database model

Tags: ios, core-data, database-design

I have an issue in converting simple relational database model to Core Data data model. Problem comes when I try to create unique ID's and different kinds of relations. How should I convert relational data model to Core Data model?

My database model:https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6ycu14tT4SGMkt1aGdUa2dlYTQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: It's fairly straight forward - you have the schema for each table. Make those your Entities verbatim. Then for any foreign keys you have, make that a relationship on the entities.

Comment: Yes, it is true, but the problem is, that, normally in database model foreign key is an attribute which points to another table attribute (primary key). Here I don't see any foreign or primary keys neither. Only table points to table relationship. How to deal with it?

Comment: For CoreData instead of using foreign/primary keys, you just point to the other table itself. There are no foreign keys. The whole entity (table) is the 'foreign key'. Lecture will have a relationship to subject (and hence, lecture will have a full reference to the subject object). Similarly, Exam will have a relationship to the Subject Entity.

Comment: Them, how to deal with different types of relationships? One to one, one to many, many to many...? For example, how to define relationship between professor and lecture?

Comment: You can define that in the CoreData editor within xCode by selecting the relationship. You can define all of the one to one, one to many, the inverse relationships, the delete rule (nullify vs cascade), etc. You'd be best to actually go through a tutorial, all of your questions can be answered by doing a quick one. You can do this literally after a 20 minute tutorial.

Comment: Can you recommend me one? :).

Comment: Thank you. Actually I did watched some tutorials, but I didn't succeed  to find an answer to my questions...

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started.

Comment: Ok... This doesn't answer my question... Please, can you give me example and I will figure it out? How to create core data model with two of those database tables: Professor and lecture (many-to-many relationship). I would be very helpful.

Comment: No, it does. Look at the tutorial, it sets you up with a one-to-one relationship. Literally search and find one-to-one relationship. Look at the picture above it, it shows you a checkbox for: Plural (To-Many relationship). You do this on the arrow from Professor to Lecture, then Lecture to Professor. If you even search "setting many to many relationship coredata" you get the apple doc as the first result which also shows you how to set this. If you can't at least search on your own then you won't get far in programming.